Zorrin OS 17.2 Network Adepter Driver Issue
Today I switched to Zorrin OS version 17.2 (for Ubuntu version 22.04) from Windows OS. I downloaded the driver and even tried to download it with dkms, but dkms was giving --configure error and then I downloaded it with make. Actually, the adapter is now visible, the light is on, but when I select "Settings > Wi-Fi > TP-Link Archer T2U PLUS" adapter, no network appears in “Visible Networks”. What could be the reason for this?
Information
uname -r = 6.8.0-49-generic
Zorrin OS version 17.2 corresponds to Ubuntu version 22.04.
Wi-Fi Adapter = TP-Link Archer T2U
